# Adobe Flex (Mobile): How server can notify client when some event get fired in server

Tags: wcf, apache-flex, push-notification

How to implement push notification (like Facebook notification) in Adobe Flex for mobile application.

I'm currently try to find out how the server can notify the client when some event get fired in the server. I'm building WCF Service for communication between server and client.

Anyone can suggest or provide me any guidance?

Thanks.

Comment: User a server side software that supports push notifications.  LiveCycle should do this, and I believe so GraniteDS does too.  I'm sure there are other non-java based options, such as WebORB.